# Is the convergence linear, superlinear, quadratic?

Tags: convergence-divergence

> The **Fibonacci sequence** is generated by the formulas 
>   \begin{cases}  r_0=1 & r_1=1\\ r_{n+1}=r_n+r_{n-1} \end{cases}  The
>   sequence therefore starts out $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, \dots$.
>   Prove that the sequence $[2r_n/r_{n-1}]$ converges to $1+\sqrt{5}$. Is
>   the convergence linear, superlinear, quadratic?

***Proof:*** Suppose we are given the following recurrence relation $$r_{n+1}=r_n+r_{n-1},$$ where $r_0=1$ and $r_1=1$. We want to show that the sequence $[2r_n/r_{n-1}]$ converges to $1+\sqrt{5}$. i.e. We want to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{2r_n}{r_{n-1}}=1+\sqrt{5}.$$ Before, we prove this limit is true, we need to find the solution to this recurrence relation with the given initial conditions.

The corresponding characteristic polynomial to the recurrence relation is $$p(\lambda)=\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0.$$ Hence the roots of the characteristic polynomial are $\lambda=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Hence the general solution for the relation is $$r_n=A\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+B\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n.$$

Next, we want to find the values of $A$ and $B$ with the given initial conditions. With the starting values $r_0=1$ and $r_1=1$, we get the following system of equations:
\begin{cases}
1=r_0=A+B \\
1=r_1=A\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+B\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)
\end{cases}

Multiply the first equation by $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=r_0=A\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+B\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \\
1=r_1=A\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+B\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)
\end{cases}

Next, subtract equation (1) from equation (2), which results with
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{5}=1}{2}=B\sqrt{5} \iff B=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}.$$ 
Furthermore $$A=1-\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}=1-\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}=1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}.$$
Hence, the general solution for the relation is 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
r_n & =\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n \\
& =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n+1}-(1-\sqrt{5})^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}\right].
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Now we can show that the sequence $[2r_n/r_{n-1}]$ converges to $1+\sqrt{5}$. 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{2r_n}{r_{n-1}} 
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n+1}-(1-\sqrt{5})^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}\right]}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n}-(1-\sqrt{5})^{n}}{2^{n}}\right]} \\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n+1}-(1-\sqrt{5})^{n+1}}{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n}-(1-\sqrt{5})^{n}} \\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n+1}-(1-\sqrt{5})^{n+1}}{(1+\sqrt{5})^n}}{\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{n}-(1-\sqrt{5})^{n}}{(1+\sqrt{5})^n}} \\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{(1+\sqrt{5})-(1-\sqrt{5})\cdot \left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n}}{1-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n}} \\
& = \dfrac{(1+\sqrt{5})-(1-\sqrt{5})\cdot 0}{1-0} \\
& = 1+\sqrt{5}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

***Note:*** Since $0<\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}<1$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}\right)^{n}=0.$$

To finish the question I need to state whether the convergence is linear, superlinear, or quadratic. I know that

- If the limit equals 0, then the convergence is superlinear.
- If the limit equals 1, then the convergence is linear.
- If the limit equals 2, then the convergence is quadratic.

However, my limit is equal to $1+\sqrt{5}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that the value of the limit of the expression determines the speed of convergence ?

Comment: No. I just assumed because it was a follow-up question that I needed to use the value of the limit.

Comment: Check [rate of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) on wikipedia.

Comment: So to make sure I need to compute the limit of $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{|r_{n+1}-L|}{|r_n-L|}$$ where $L=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and then just use my conditions above to determine that it's either superlinear, linear, or quadratic?

Comment: You are using $r_n$ here in your most recent comment, but you aren't asked whether the terms in the Fibonacci sequence converge and how fast they do (*they dont*), you are asked to discuss the convergence of *the ratio of consecutive Fibonacci terms*.  I.e. you should be investigating $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\frac{r_{n+1}}{r_n}-L|}{|\frac{r_n}{r_{n-1}}-L|}$$  According to the wiki article, if the limit exists and is strictly between $0$ and $1$, then it converges linearly.  If the limit exists and is zero, then it converges superlinearly.  Quadratic is a special case of superlinear

Comment: So then what should my $L$ be? Is $1+\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: You need to have $L$ be whatever the limit is so that you have both the numerator and the denominator approaching zero simultaneously.  In the way I wrote it above, $L$ would be $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  If you want $L$ to be $1+\sqrt{5}$ then instead of $\frac{r_{n+1}}{r_n}$ you should use instead $\frac{2r_{n+1}}{r_n}$.  Similarly the fraction on the bottom will change as well.

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of writing and make it easier to  check your  algebra for errors, if you let $(1+\sqrt 5\;)/2=f$ and ($-1+\sqrt 5\;)/2=g=-f^{-1}.$

Comment: @JMoravitz I did the limit using the second approach however I got $\dfrac{2+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ has the value of the limit. But $\dfrac{2+\sqrt{5}}{2}>2.$

Comment: That should not be possible.  That would imply that the earlier you are in the sequence the closer you are to the limit, which directly contradicts the concept of convergence.  If done correctly, the *only* possible values should be in the range $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to match your notation: Let $r_n$ represent the $n$'th Fibonacci number, let $q_n=\frac{2r_n}{r_{n-1}}$, and let $L=1+\sqrt{5}$

In the first part of the problem, you should have shown $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}q_n=L$

We now investigate what happens to the limit:

$$(\dagger):~~~~~~~~~\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|q_{n+1}-L|}{|q_{n}-L|}$$

$q_{n+1}$ will tend to be closer to $L$ than $q_{n}$ implying that $|q_{n+1}-L|<|q_{n}-L|$ implying that the limit $(\dagger)$ above will if it exists be somewhere in the range $[0,1]$.  If the limit is $1$ we say that $q_n$ converges to $L$ "sublinearly", if the limit is between $0$ and $1$ we say that $q_n$ converges to $L$ "linearly", and if the limit is $0$ we say that $q_n$ converges to $L$ "superlinearly."  In the case that it is sublinear or superlinear, we can futher classify just how quickly or slowly that is by raising the denominator to various powers and investigating *those* limits.

Now... again, we are tasked with investigating the limit $(\dagger)$.  Remembering that $q_n=\frac{2r_n}{r_{n-1}}$ and that $r_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$ where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Notice that $\frac{L}{2}=\varphi$ and that $\varphi\cdot \psi=-1$.

We have then $q_n=2\cdot \frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1}}$.  We have now $q_{n+1}-L=2\cdot \frac{\varphi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}-\varphi(\varphi^n-\psi^n)}{\varphi^n-\psi^n}$

$=2\cdot \frac{\varphi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}-\varphi^{n+1}-\psi^{n-1}}{\varphi^n-\psi^n}=2\cdot \frac{-\psi^{n+1}-\psi^{n-1}}{\varphi^n-\psi^n}$

Similarly we calculate $q_{n}-L$ to be $2\cdot \frac{-\psi^n-\psi^{n-2}}{\varphi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1}}$

> As a sanity check here, notice that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|q_n-L|=0$ as the numerator approaches zero while the denominator grows large.  This confirms, or rather rederives, what we should have learned in the earlier part of the question.

So this leads us to our limit $(\dagger)$ being:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|q_{n+1}-L|}{|q_n-L|}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|2\cdot \frac{-\psi^{n+1}-\psi^{n-1}}{\varphi^n-\psi^n}|}{|2\cdot \frac{-\psi^n-\psi^{n-2}}{\varphi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1}}|}=$

Which after a bit more algebra and a little bit of handwaving results in

$\frac{\frac{|\psi^2+\psi|}{|\psi+1|}}{\varphi}=\frac{|\psi|}{\varphi}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{1+\sqrt{5}}\approx 0.382$

> The handwaving comes into play when we try to move the different parts of the fraction around to get like groups together.  The group of the form $\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1}}$ we notice that as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\psi^n=0$ the only terms that truly survive are the $\varphi'$s.  This can be made more formal, but this suffices for now.

I.e. twice the ratio of consecutive fibonacci terms converges to $L$ linearly.